# How to select the #text column in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a xpath query that has a result like so:

```
Name   #text
----  ------
3     33
```

I get the result after a pipleline ending with `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node`

I want to store the value 33 in a variable so how can I pipe this result into something an only keep the #text column and after that only keep the value?

Comment: when i load XML into an object, i can address the `#text` property just like any other. use `$Var.Prop.SubProp.#text`. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Is there a way to use a pipeline?

Comment: `... |Select-Object -ExpandProperty '#text'` (`InnerText` might also work in place of `#text`)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thanks I did not think I needed the quotes

Comment: @David - i would use `ForEach-Object` and then use `$_.Prop.SubProp.#text`, but you can also use nested calls to `Select-Object`. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey what is the deal with _[grin]_?

Comment: @David - it more-or-less accurately reflects my emotional state. since text lacks all the usual side-band communication, i add emoticons. since my eyesight is pretty poor, i use spelled out emoticons - `[*grin*]` instead of `:)`.